# Como puedo realizar un trigger que elimine luego de insertar?

Tags: php, mysql, trigger

Estoy intentando realizar un trigger que se ejecute cuando haya pasado los datos de una tabla a otra, pero no tengo muy en claro la sintaxis y en donde debe ir, tengo dos tablas, current_products y finished_products, el trigger deberia ir en current_products o finished_products? agregando que la sentencia se ejecuta por php.

aqui el codigo:

php:

```
  $query = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
    (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
    FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room");
    $query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
```

ahi insertara en finished_products los datos de current_products, en tal caso yo pienso que el trigger deberia ir en current_products, asi: CREATE TRIGGER DELETE_CURRENT_PRODUCT_AI AFTER INSERT on `current_products` ya aqui no se como iria la sentencia, agregando que tiene que ser igual la habitacion para que se ejecute, gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Tu trigger deberia ir en la tabla en la que se inserta y deberia ser un `AFTER INSERT` ahora, para ello debes considerar que si hay una relación (PK-FK) entonces no te va a funcionar ya que generarias un error logico al querer borrar una referencia de tu propia tabla, si no hay una referencia relacional entonces puedes hacer algo mas o menos como lo siguiente

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_finished_product_finished 
AFTER INSERT
ON yourDataBase.finished_products FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM current_products WHERE NEW.room = room
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Aqui basicamente le estas diciendo que despues de insertar un nuevo registro ent u tabla `finished_products` te elimine el registro de `current_products` que contenga el mismo dato `room` considera que este ultimo puedes cambiar por tu ID.

En caso de tener relacion puedes solo cambiar una bandera dentro de `current_product`.

Espero haberte ayudado

Puedes leer como crear un trigger en [24.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)